# Immutable Strings with Ternary Operator

Tags: immutability, operator-keyword, ternary

I was working on a project and I wrote this piece of code
`dna = Math.random() > PERCENT ? dna + LETTERA : dna + LETTERB;` and I don't exactly know why it works.

`dna` is a `String`
`LETTERA` and `LETTERB` are `char`

The code itself works how I want it to, the problem is I don't understand why. I thought that Strings in Java were immutable so when I say `dna + LETTERA` I should receive an error, but I don't.

At first when I wrote the code I did not use `dna + LETTERB` I used `dna += LETTERB` but I receive the following error, `Syntax error on token "+=", + expected`

If you write something like:
`String testStr = "test";`
`testStr + "example";`
you get an error `InvalidAssignmentOperator` so can someone explain to me why you can add to a String within a ternary operator like this?

Comment: The reason why it works is because with the ternary operator I wrote starts with `dna =`  I was confused why `dna + LETTERA` works but if you look at the entire statement it's `dna = dna + LETTERA`. It all makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string + something` creates a new `String`, so the original `String` is unchanged (it has to be since it's immutable) and there's a **new** immutable `String` created with the new character on the end of it.

So that's why the ternary operator works fine. It'll create one or the other new `String` on either side of the `:` (depending on the condition before `?`) and give you back the one it created.

---

The error with the code you gave is different for me, so I'm unsure:

```
error: not a statement
        testStr + "example";
                ^
```

I think you might have meant this:

```java
String testStr = "test";
testStr += "example";
```

That compiles. The reason why is that the object `"test"` is immutable, but not the variable `testStr`. Unless the variable is marked `final` by you, you can have the variable refer to a different object later.

It's a bit like if you erase an address from an envelope and write a different address. You haven't changed anything about the house at that address (you haven't mutated the house). You've just changed which house you're referring to (you've just mutated the envelope that refers to the house).

At first, `testStr` refers to `"test"`. Later, it refers to `"testexample"`. The old, immutable `"test"` is still there until it's garbage collected. It wasn't changed. A completely new `String` was created and now the variable, which isn't immutable, refers to a new immutable `String`.